# PyGtk3, Hide Cursor on Selectable Label

Tags: pygtk

I can make a selectable label in pygtk3 with the `set_selectable` method. But I can't hide the cursor of a selectable label. Is there a method to do this?

Comment: You can try editing your question to bump it to the top again.

Answer (score 0):

First off, generally you might to reconsider disabling the cursor. Without it, you cannot select (part of) the text easily. If you only want the entire text, it's probably easier to do a `label.get_text()` to obtain the text.

If, for some obscure reason, you *do* want to change (or hide) the cursor, you can use the `enter` and `leave` events of a widget. Label widgets do not have those, so you have to insert the `GtkLabel` into a `GtkEventBox` first. Here's how to do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  test_selectable_label.py
#
#  Copyright 2017 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
#


from gi.repository import Gtk

class TestWindow(Gtk.VBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__()
        self.set_spacing(5)

        sel_label = Gtk.Label("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
        sel_label.set_selectable(True)

        sel_evbox = Gtk.EventBox()
        sel_evbox.add(sel_label)
        sel_evbox.connect("enter_notify_event", self.enter_label)
        sel_evbox.connect("leave_notify_event", self.leave_label)
        self.pack_start(sel_evbox, False, False, 0)

        label = Gtk.Label()
        self.pack_start(label, False, False, 0)

    def enter_label(self, wdg, event):
        print("Entering")

    def leave_label(self, wdg, event):
        print("Leaving")


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.connect("destroy", lambda x: Gtk.main_quit())

        self.add(TestWindow())
        self.show_all()

    def run(self):
        Gtk.main()


def main(args):
    mainwdw = MainWindow()
    mainwdw.run()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

I didn't implement the actual hiding/showing of the cursor. One way would be to make it transparent (see the `override_cursor` method of `GtkWidget`. `set_style` would be another.

Comment: thanks for comment. but it is not working. see this picture https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByGGW28GJgmoVHJjV2hBa3FrLVE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you complete the enter_label and leave_label methods in the program? Asi it is, the program only detects the entering and exiting from the label. (See the comment below the listing, about override_cursor and set_style)

Comment: i can't complete these functions because i don't know how does it complete